# Scripts within SpreadSheet work slowly and whole file is unable to use

Tags: arrays, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, optimization

I have created a SpreadSheet where I use several scripts, basically for "hide/unhide" of columns and rows. These functions loop over all existing Sheets within one SpreadSheet. I find the file unable to work on while there are several Sheets created.

Is there any way to speed up the execution of app scripts?

Here's an example of scrips which are used there:

`

```
function hideColumns() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get all sheets except 'Arkusz4'
  const sheets = ss.getSheets().filter(s => s.getName() != '!DEFINICJE!');

  // loop through the sheets
sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    let dropDown = sheet.getRange('B35:C35').getValue();
    if (dropDown == "1") {sheet.showColumns(4,9);
sheet.hideColumns(4,9);}
    else if (dropDown == "2") {sheet.showColumns(4,9);
sheet.hideColumns(5,8);}
    else if (dropDown == "3") {sheet.showColumns(4,9);
sheet.hideColumns(6,7);}
    else if (dropDown == "4") {sheet.showColumns(4,9);
sheet.hideColumns(7,6);}
    else if (dropDown == "5") {sheet.showColumns(4,9);
sheet.hideColumns(8,5);}
    else if (dropDown == "6") {sheet.showColumns(4,9);
sheet.hideColumns(9,4);}
    else if (dropDown == "7") {sheet.showColumns(4,9);
sheet.hideColumns(10,3);}
    else if (dropDown == "8") {sheet.showColumns(4,9);
sheet.hideColumns(11,2);}
    else if (dropDown == "9") {sheet.showColumns(4,9);
sheet.hideColumns(12,1);}
    else if (dropDown ==  "10") {sheet.showColumns(4,9);}
    else if (dropDown ==  "") {sheet.showColumns(4,9);}
  })
}
```

`

Each code consists of:

- "get all sheets"
- "loop through all sheets"

I would be grateful for your help in this matter.

I tried to set the triggers differently or even lower the number of sheets in the file. Unfortunately, it did not help and users still have problems and are unable to work on the file.

Would that be possible to implement "array" functions to speed up the execution of scripts?

Comment: This `let dropDown = sheet.getRange('B35:C35').getValue();` is the same as this `let dropDown = sheet.getRange('B35').getValue();`

Comment: It takes time to modify the ui.  I doubt the anything will run much faster

Comment: I have a question for you.  Why do all sheets?  Unless the dropdown on a sheet is changed the hidden and shown columns would remain as they were the last time you accessed that sheet.  You could use onEdit(e) to examine the value in the dropdown on that sheet and set the column visibility if the dropdown changes.

Comment: @TheWizEd - yes, actually the script needs to be executed only when the value from the dropdown list is changed. So do you suggest that this function does not have to be looped or so? Apart from the loop and taking all sheets, I also set a trigger for the script to run while the value is changed. What would be your suggestion to alter the code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using onEdit(e) to check the value of a dropdown and hide certain columns.  Note that a Data Validation Dropdown is a string not a number.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    // limit to cell A1
    if( ( e.range.getRow() === 1 ) && ( e.range.getColumn() ===1 ) ) {
      let sheet = e.range.getSheet();
      sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getDataRange());
      switch(Number(e.value)) {
        case 1:
          sheet.hideColumns(4,5);
          break;
        case 2:
          sheet.hideColumns(5,4);
          break;
        case 3:
          sheet.hideColumns(6,3);
          break;
        case 4:
          sheet.hideColumns(7,2);
          break;
        case 5:
          sheet.hideColumns(8,1);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(err);
  }
}
```

Or more simply

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    // limit to cell A1
    if( ( e.range.getRow() === 1 ) && ( e.range.getColumn() ===1 ) ) {
      let sheet = e.range.getSheet();
      sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getDataRange());
      let value = Number(e.value)-1;
      sheet.hideColumns(4+value,5-value);
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions.

When I tried to put the second code into AppScript it returns "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range'). I changed the values in getRow() and getColumn() to take a range from the dropdown list. Where do I make a mistake?

Sorry for my incompetence, I am a huge beginner at this.

Comment: You can not run this from script editor, e is undefined.  This runs when you edit a cell in a sheet.